# Setting the rule for split footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, split

My university's editorial office has some funny and detailed stipulations on theses and dissertations, written and set years ago, but without any official LaTeX support anymore `:(`. (You just have to hope to get lucky that an editor working there when you need consultation knows LaTeX as much as you or more.)  My problem concerns the horizontal rule above footnotes.

If I split footnotes, then the rule separating the footnotes from the text must be different from the horizontal rule normally separating the footnotes from the body text.

In my document I have `\renewcommand\footnoterule{\kern-3pt \hrule width 1in \kern 2.6pt}` because the default rule needs to be 1 inch. If a footnote continues on a second page, then the footnote divider needs to be 6 inches long.

For the longer horizontal rule needed to separate continuing footnote text from the body text, I added `\usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc}` as well as `\def\splitfootnoterule{\kern-3pt \hrule width 6in \kern 2.6pt}`.

When I compile with lualatex, I get no errors, but the code for both footnote markers is only 1 inch.

What should I do to make the horizontal rule above split footnotes (and not the regular footnote rules) be longer?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: don't redefine `\footnoterule`, but `\pagefootnoterule` to change the appearance of the normal footnote rule

Answer (score 2):

That did it, @Robert. Thank you!

For others looking at this. `\footnoterule` is for *all* footnotes.

To deal with separate footnote rules, I need to redefine the default footnote rule with `\pagefootnoterule` and then `\splitfootnoterule` for the other kind.